# C# SQL query result to textboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

Newbie here, working on converting a little program I had in python/sqlite to C#/SQL Server. I'm having a bit of an issue with getting a SQL query to write its results to two textboxes (textBox1 and textBox2) based upon the selection of a combobox (which does populate correctly, by the way). Here's my attempted code, just need the last bit that writes the result to the textboxes:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        string selected = (this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString();
        var selected2 = from branches in branchesDataSet.branches
                        where branches.branchCode == "selected"
                        select new
                        {
                            branches.branchCode
                            branches.branchName
                        };
```

I've tried passing it to an array, to a list, just can't seem to get it to give the result, just the identifier. Any help? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have at the moment is an `IQueryable<T>` for some unpronounceable anonymous-type `T`. I *assume*, since you are using text-boxes, that you expect at most one row, so:

```
var row = selected2.FirstOrDefault();
if(row == null) {
    textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = "n/a";
} else {
    textBox1.Text = row.branchCode;
    textBox2.Text = row.branchName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, modified my code, including an error I had with the selection (string selected = comboBox1.Text;), but I keep getting a n/a return. I know there's data, I just entered the data, and a SQL query gives me the data. Definitely on the right track though.

Comment: @b0b heh; you probably mean: `where branches.branchCode == selected`, not `where branches.branchCode == "selected"`. Note the quotes.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Something so simple! Comes from trying to translate from one language to another without the required experience.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use textbox this mean you query one row:

```
var onerow= selected2.FirstOrDefault();

if(row == null) { textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = "n/a";} 

else { textBox1.Text = onerow.branchCode; textBox2.Text = onerow.branchName; }
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for just verbatimely repeating what Marc said.